# Keras callbacks in custom epoch loop

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I use keras to train an LSTM. The input sequences are of different length. Lets say the sequences have lengths between 1 and `num_seq`. Therefore, I group the sequences by length in each epoch in order to use a batch size > 1:

```
for epoch in xrange(nb_epochs):
 for i in range(1,num_seq):
  X,y = get_sequences(length=i)
  model.fit(X,y,batch_size=100,epochs=1, validation_split=0.1, callbacks=None)
```

Because I use a custom loop over the epochs, callbacks which use the epoch information do not work properly (e.g. the tensorboard, history, etc). What would be a way around this problem? Is there a way to tell the fit function, which epoch it currently does?

Comment: Did you try `initial_epoch` parameter of the `fit` method? Maybe it does what you need.

Comment: I think initial_epoch works if you want to resume a training.If you want to train 100 epochs, stop after 50 and then want to continue, then you would want to set initial_epoch to 50 (or 51). However, I think this only works if `epochs` > `initial_epoch`

Comment: Also, setting initial_epoch does not take changing learning rates into account, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When doing manipulation on your training data during training you should use `model.train_on_batch` incrementally or - better yet - use [`fit_generator`](https://keras.io/models/model/#fit_generator) which lets you define a python generator that produces `(x,y)` tuples for each batch. This then takes care of the proper invocation of callbacks as well.

For example:

```
def train_gen():
   while True:
       for i in range(1,num_seq):
           X,y = get_sequences(length=i)
           yield X, y
model.fit_generator(train_gen, steps_per_epoch=num_seq)
```

The downside of this is that you have to do the batching yourself and also have to supply the validation split yourself which you can do with a generator as well (therefore you can reuse most of the code).

Comment: What is the advantage of using `model.train_on_batch()` instead of `model.fit`()? The fit generator approach looks really promsing. Thanks for the hint!